# complex integration on a closed contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Sorry for my broken English.

I am a physics undergrad and quite poor at math.

I have to prove that integration of $\int_C (z-a)^n dz=0$. $z$ and $a$ is a complex number and $n$ is an integer except $-1$ and $c$ is an arbitrary closed contour.

I know how to integrate if the contour is a circle. but the problem is, it is an arbitrary contour.

I googled and searched a lot but could not find a solution. If this is duplicate, then I apologize.
Please help me!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is enough to prove the equality holds over circle by using the Cauchy's integral theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If $ n \in \mathbb Z$ and $n \ne-1$, then the function $(z-a)^n$ has the antiderivative $\frac{(z-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}$.

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the fact that $(z-a)^n$ has a primitive: $F(z)=\frac{(z-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}$. So, if the domain of your closed loop $\gamma$ is $[a,b]$,$$\int_\gamma(z-a)^n\,\mathrm dz=F\bigl(\gamma(b)\bigr)-F\bigl(\gamma(a)\bigr)=0.$$